# Close or improve "Do you use X?" questions?

Tags: discussion

There are some questions like [Effectiveness of technical analysis techniques: Any supporting studies?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/effectiveness-of-technical-analysis) which may come down to "do you use technical analysis?"  (Or it may actually be clarified to something else; it's just an example.)

If it's the former, I feel we should close them.  There's no objective answer, just a bunch of people who happen to use it or not.

I'd be much happier with people asking

- given Y, should I use X?
- is there theoretical support for X?
- is X commonly used?

I guess this may be almost a meta faq.

Comment: The example question's title was modified to focus on the second part of the body, which asks "What studies exist which show evidence for whether or not different techniques work?" ... I agree the first part of "do you use" isn't really useful.  But I wouldn't close the question because the second part has merit.  Still, your question is a good one, even if the example is not a perfect example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not advocate closing them. I would advocate editing them. You have proposed several ways the questions could be restructured. You could also ask:

- What are the benefits/drawbacks of X?
- How does X compare to Y?
- Who is the target audience for X? Or what type of investors typically find X helpful?

(The example I'm thinking of is financial websites: Comparing Yahoo Finance, Morningstar, Bloomberg, Motley Fool, etc.)

[The only question I have had closed](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7018/does-the-japan-earthquake-make-this-a-good-time-to-enter-the-msci-eafe-fund) ... was legitimately beyond the scope of this forum and there was no apparent way of rephrasing or restructuring it as I have described here. Those types of questions should definitely be closed.

Disclaimer: This answer probably reflects my own bias. I don't like closing questions. It feels mean. And I don't like having my questions closed. It's disappointing. Some may find it frustrating or embarrassing.